# Connect two custom controls using outlets

Tags: cocoa, swift

I wrote two custom controls (a FragmentBar and a FragmentLegend - both inheriting from NSView) and I would like to connect those two controls using outlets being wired up using Interface Builder (the FragmentLegend shall have a connection to the FragmentBar).

I tried creating an @IBOutlet of type FragmentBar within the FragmentLegend class. This outlet is visible in Interface Builder but cannot be connected to the FragmentBar. As soon as I change the type of the outlet from "FragmentBar" to "NSView" it is possible to use Interface Builder to establish this connection.

Now I wonder if there is a way to declare the outlet with the correct type (instead of NSView - which would need to be casted to the correct type).

```
class AbFragmentBarLegend: NSView
{
    @IBOutlet var fragmentBar: AbFragmentBar    // Cannot be connected
    @IBOutlet var fragmentBar: NSView           // Can be connected, but needs casting
}
```

Can someone give me a hint?

I'm using Swift with Xcode 6 Beta 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in Beta 2. Update to Beta 3 and it should work. 
Tested it just now with a custom UIButton.

Comment: Looks like you're right. I just tried it with two custom controls in Beta 3 and it indeed seems to work. Thanks for that :-)